# How can I run an Android emulator on Ubuntu running on VmWare

Tags: vmware, android-studio, emulation, android-emulator

I am trying to develop react-native apps on Ubuntu running on Vmware workstation on my windows machine because of issues coding on Windows. But I can't seem to set up Android studio emulator on the virtual machine, when trying to set it up it won't let me download a system image, see below:

[Android emulator issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hhgwo.png)

So I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions of how to get an emulator running on my Ubuntu running on Vmware?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: "A system image must be selected to continue" - why can't you do that?

Comment: the button isn't showing to allow me to download the image, I'm not sure if its caused by window issues by being run in Vmware, thats what I'm trying to figure out....

Comment: Use docker and WSL that is beter. See my response [https://stackoverflow.com/a/62692404/4362430](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62692404/4362430)